# How to solve this logic question without going directly to truth tables?

Tags: logic

Which of the following equations is equivalent to $(x \lor y) \implies z$?

The answer is E - but how can we solve it without using truth tables directly - using little theorems and identities?

A: $(x \implies y)\vee(y \implies z)$

B: $(x \implies z)\vee(y \implies z)$

C: $(x \wedge z) \implies y$

D: $(x \implies y)\wedge(y \implies z)$

E: $(x \implies z)\wedge(y \implies z)$

Comment: for example do you know the [Conjunctive_normal_form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) of boolean functions ?

Comment: Have you tried to translate them all using $a\implies b\equiv \lnot a\lor b$, and then using distributive properties and DeMorgan's law?

Comment: The identity from implication to negation and or is really useful here. Thanks @Arthur

Answer (score 1):

The answer is (E). You gain this by resorting to the definition of implication, $x\implies y \equiv \neg x \vee y $ and the usual logic algebra.

\begin{align*}
 (x \implies z) \vee (y \implies z) &\equiv (\neg x \vee z) \vee ( \neg y \vee z)\\
 &\equiv \neg x \vee z \vee  \neg y \vee z\\
 &\equiv (\neg x \vee \neg y) \vee z \vee z\\
 &\equiv \neg(x \land y) \vee z\\
 &\equiv (x \land y) \implies z
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is (B), not (E).

Your condition is true unless $z$ is false and $x$ and $y$ are both true.  That's also the only way (B) can be false.  But (E) is false if $x$ is true and $z$ is false, no matter what $y$ is (in particular, if $y$ is false).

Comment: Thanks for pointing out an error; the first equation should actually read (x OR y) -- i guess the answer is really E now.